# How do I load a new dictionary in WinEdT 9?

Tags: winedt, dictionaries

I downloaded a Brazilian Portuguese dictionary from WinEdT with file name br.  Its properties box says it is a "Text Document (.dic)", which may help below but i do not know.

I placed it in a file folder called `br` in `C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Dict`

WinEdT Help gives clearly written instructions, which do not actually say what to do.  They say several times:

> When you select the Dictionary Manager branch in the Options
>   Interface, the toolbar in that interface contains a button that allows
>   you to start the Dictionary Manager dialog.

Nothing at all like the dialogue box shown in WinEdt Help opened but I was taken to a file called Dictionaries.ini where i saw

```
[BUILD]

DICTIONARY=""
  FILE=""
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER=""
  LOAD_ON_START=1
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1

REQUIRES=20100208
```

I filled it in this way:

```
[BUILD]

DICTIONARY="brazil"
  FILE="C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 9\Dict\br"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER=""
  LOAD_ON_START=1
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1

REQUIRES=20100208
```

That may not be what they wanted, but I do not know what they wanted.

That part of code still reads that way now.  But nothing I can do (including restarting WinEdT ) makes it spell check source files in Portuguese.

What should I have done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have put your dictionary definition before the line

```
[DICTIONARIES]
```

in the file `Dictionaries.ini`, so when the relative configuration section has not started yet.

Putting the lines

```
DICTIONARY="brazil"
  FILE="%B\Dict\br.dic"
  ENABLED=1
  MODE_FILTER=""
  LOAD_ON_START=1
  SAVE_ON_EXIT=1
  ADD_NEW_WORDS=0
  USE_FOR_COMPLETION=1
  ALLOW_COMPOUNDED_WORDS=1
```

after the above line and then pressing <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file will work.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to do all the work yourself, revert the changes and let the macro [InstallDict](http://www.winedt.org/macros/winedt/InstallDict.html) from winedt.org do it for you. It suffices to follow the instructions and it will install the dictionary for you!

Comment: P.S.: be sure that you've downloaded the unicode version of the dictionary....

Comment: That sounds right.  But when I hit <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> I get "Initialization Error! (long name of file) unrecognized keyword."

Comment: I forgot to change the line `FILE=....`. Now should be OK.